# How can I find my home again?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I started my Minecraft server a little while ago. So I flew a good distance away from the place I started and began to build. Later I died down at the bedrock, and so spawned at my starting point again, and now I can not find my buildings!

How do I find the home I built again?

Comment: I always errect a sort of tower next to my house and put a torch on it or look for some mountain nearby and put torches on top there too, on the edges. This way it is easier to spot it from "far away".

Answer (score 6):

You could use a external terrain view to look for certain blocks, such as workbenches or furnaces, that you would have in you house, or just look for distinctive patterns near you house.

In future I suggest building a bed so you spawn back in your house. Or you can use F3 to find it's coordinates and walk back if you get lost.

Comment: Another strategy would be to build some kind of beacon (perhaps a large tower with torches on the top) near the house that can be seen from far away. Of course, this will only work if you have your render distance set to far.

Answer (score 0):

I would use MCedit to find the buildings, and if you want to you can then move your spawn to somewhere close to or inside the buildings.

Answer (score -1):

you have to have portal to the nether near or in your house and you have to have obsidian with you or just find it when your lost you need a diamond pickax to break it. you get obsidian from when water puts out a lava. you are going to need water and lava to make obsidian. you need to put four blocks of obsidian in a line then on each end of the line of obsidian you put five blocks of obsidian on top of the last block of four peaces of obsidian and then connect the ends like a square and the light one of the obsidian blocks on fire with flint and steel. so if you don't have a portal to the nether near your house you can not find your house this way. but if you do you have a portal to the nether near your house. great!!!! then you need to build another portal to the nether wherever you are right in front of you and go inside of it then you leave the portal and you will end up at the spot that you built your other portal near your house if this worked for you yay! but if it didn't I am sorry.

Comment: Hello, wall of text. We meet again.