# im in single player minecraft and im lost

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding my house in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft)

I am in single player creative minecraft and I went to the netherworld. I got lost in the netherworld, and made another portal and went back to surface. But I have no idea where my house is. I have been searching around for an hour and cant find it. Any help is great. Thanks

Comment: Likely to be a duplicate of either http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29516/finding-my-house-in-minecraft or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38585/how-can-i-find-my-home-again

Comment: Note that moving a certain distance in the Nether corresponds to moving 8 times as far in the overworld, so you are probably very far away from home.

Comment: Try heading towards x: 0 z: 0. Your house may be near there, or at least in the general area. If you are over 1,000 blocks away, try heading into the Nether to travel; it will save you 7/8 of the trouble.